# Unsupported engine node / NPM only when building in Docker

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, alpine-linux, nvm

I have a dependency in my `package.json` which itself has the following dependency:

`"node-rdkafka": "^2.5.0",`

Using `nvm` on my local machine and setting my node version to `8.9.1`, and my `npm` version is `5.5.1`, I can **successfully** run

`npm install node-rdkafka@2.7.1`

But when running the same thing (i.e `npm install`) from within my docker image:

`FROM node:10.13.0-alpine` or `FROM node:8.9.1-alpine`

I get the following error:

```
npm ERR! notsup Unsupported engine for node-rdkafka@2.7.1: wanted: {"node":">=12.0.0"} (current: {"node":"10.13.0","npm":"6.4.1"})
npm ERR! notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: node-rdkafka@2.7.1
npm ERR! notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: node-rdkafka@2.7.1
npm ERR! notsup Required: {"node":">=12.0.0"}
npm ERR! notsup Actual:   {"npm":"6.4.1","node":"10.13.0"}
```

Any ideas about this inconsistency?

I clearly dont need a node version this high. But it says I do.

Comment: are you sure that it is working correctly on your local environment (the one with nvm) from the logs you could expect that there were probably some breaking changes that should not be allowed, if anything it's not an issue with docker but with your local node install that tricks the library to ignore node version

Comment: the weird thing is that the minimal setup (simple docker file with `FROM node:10.13.0
RUN npm install node-rdkafka@2.7.1`) builds correctly for me, granted i don't use alpine because rdkafka required python executable and some other stuff i don't want to deal with settting up... could you provide entire `package.json` and `Dockerfile` ?

Comment: Hmm.. I still get the same problem with `FROM node:10.13.0`

Comment: FYI it was because there was a setting `engine-strict=true` in `.npmrc` file

Answer (score 12):

Try to remove `package-lock.json` before `npm install` in Docker

```
rm package-lock.json
npm i
```

Comment: That doesn't fix it for me.

Comment: It also defeats the purpose of `package-lock.json`.

Answer (score 10):

The engines property in the `package.json` allows us to establish a range of versions.

With `>=12` is asking for a node with version 12 or greater.

Therefore, the solution would be to install the requested version:

```
FROM node:12
```

I recommend reviewing the versions currently available on Docker [here](https://hub.docker.com/_/node).

Answer (score 1):

When building old apps with a more recent nodejs, it might work perfectly fine to use older packages which had requirements on nodejs engine.

Karma package, for instance, has this requirement : `required: { node: '0.10 || 0.12 || 4 || 5 || 6 || 7' }`. But it works ok in nodejs 16.

In this case, there is a setting to transform EBADENGINE into a error or warning. It works in nodejs 16 at least.

Add or remove this line in your `~/.npmrc` :  `engine-strict=true`.

I added this flag following a tutorial, and didn't realize its impact until I wanted to build an older app.