# NPM and nodejs requirements are met, but still getting Unsupported engine error

Tags: node.js, npm, aframe

our project uses `aframe` package and don't understand why this error keeps coming up. We have tried reinstalling node and npm, downgrading aframe to a different version with no luck.  Even from their error message it looks like we satisfy the requirements.

What is going on here?

```
npm ERR! code EBADENGINE
npm ERR! engine Unsupported engine
npm ERR! engine Not compatible with your version of node/npm: aframe@1.2.0
npm ERR! notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: aframe@1.2.0
npm ERR! notsup Required: {"node":">= 4.6.0","npm":"^2.15.9"}
npm ERR! notsup Actual:   {"npm":"8.1.2","node":"v16.13.2"}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unsupported engine node / NPM only when building in Docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57924847/unsupported-engine-node-npm-only-when-building-in-docker)

Comment: Unfortunately not.  Though I'm also having those same problems using Docker

Comment: Hmm... can you try using the CDN in that case? Or maybe migrate to Yarn?